# Website scraping: python requests not downloading full site?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm having problems in scraping a website. The aim will be to scrape prices for hotels in London for certain days. For that I'm loading the below URL from booking.com and then try to search for keywords. But for some reason the requests.get doesn't download the full site. For example the URL below displays a list of hotels in my browser. Each of them showing 'Total' and the the price. However, in the below code site.find('Total') shows that no word 'Total' can be found in the string, even though it's visible in the browser. Any suggestions why this happens are appreciated.

```
import requests

url='http://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-17CAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaFCIAQGYAS64AQTIAQTYAQHoAQH4AQs;sid=1a43e0952558ac0ad0061d5b6523a7bc;dcid=1;checkin_monthday=4;checkin_year_month=2016-2;checkout_monthday=11;checkout_year_month=2016-2;city=-2601889;class_interval=1;csflt=%7B%7D;group_adults=7;group_children=0;highlighted_hotels=1192837;hp_sbox=1;label_click=undef;no_rooms=1;review_score_group=empty;room1=A%2CA%2CA%2CA%2CA%2CA%2CA;sb_price_type=total;score_min=0;si=ai%2Cco%2Cci%2Cre%2Cdi;ss=London;ssafas=1;ssb=empty;ssne=London;ssne_untouched=London&;order=price_for_two'
r=requests.get(url)

site=r.text
site.find('Total')
```

Comment: Have you tried pretty-printing `r.test` to see what you're actually getting?

Comment: Yes I have, and it's not in there

Comment: So what *is* there? It's very likely that *"Total"* is being generated by some JavaScript, which `requests` won't run, and isn't actually in the raw HTML.

Comment: I believe people use selenium for scraping dynamic websites

Comment: Is selenium the only way to generate those JavaScript outputs? And if so, is there a way to avoid it opening a browser?

Comment: You can run Selenium with PhantomJS if you want to avoid opening a browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "Total" information you're talking about is generated with Javascript in the browser. The Requests library can't generate this HTML for you because it isn't a browser environment.

To see what I'm talking about, try running that URL in a browser without Javascript.

[image]

If you want to scrape HTML that requires Javascript to run, you should look into a library that binds to a browser environment, like [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html).